# How to automatically refresh feed when user makes a new post in React Native

Tags: getstream-io

We have a simple screen based on the React Native tutorial with the following FlatFeed and StatusUpdateForm inside a StreamApp

```
<FlatFeed notify={true}  />
  <StatusUpdateForm
    feedGroup="timeline"
  />
```

We want to automatically refresh the FlatFeed when the user makes a new post using the StatusUpdateForm control

Answer (score 0):

React Native does not subscribe to the Feed. Therefore all transactions are triggered client side. Therefore you will need to write custom logic that os triggered when a post is created. If you use your own client you can wait the response form add activity, and then trigger an event that navigates you back to the feed.

This is not as simple as it is on the web React version.